# C# Removing typeof and instead passing just a class name into a function

Tags: c#, .net

Throughout my code base I have a function which takes an object and its type.

The second parameter is used to perform validation of that object type. To pass the type i have lots of typeof(..) calls like this:

```
if(Is_Valid(request_obj,typeof(User_ID)))
```

My Is_Valid function is currently declared like this:

```
public static bool Is_Valid(object objectUnderValidation, Type objectType)
```

How can i modify the Is_Valid function to call the typeof inside it and just call the function like this:

```
if(Is_Valid(request_obj,User_ID))
```

Comment: Whats the code of Is_Valid?

Comment: You could make Is_Valid into a generic method...

Comment: What is the static type of `request_obj` and what is its dynamic type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Generics:

```
public static bool Is_Valid<T>(object obj)
{
    return obj is T;
}
```

and then call this way

```
Is_Valid<YourType>(request_obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx).

```
public static bool Is_Valid<T>(T objectUnderValidation) {
  //Your code
}
```

```
if (Is_Valid(request_obj))
```

Comment: well yes and no. If the objectUnderVal is declared 'object' say, then T is object, and code in the validation that says is this a T will of course say 'yes'.YOu need to call with explicit value for T

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to clean your code up you might create an extension method and do something like this.

```
public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static bool IsValid(this object obj, Type type)
    {
        // Run your logic here.
        return true; // return Answer();
    }

    public static bool IsValid<T>(this object obj)
    {
        // Run your logic here.
        var type = typeof(T);
        return true;  // return Answer();
    }
}
```

Now your code would read:

```
request_obj.IsValid(typeof(User_ID));
```

-or-

```
request_obj.IsValid<User_ID>();
```

But you can't eliminate the typeof keyword if that is what you are asking.  Unless, of course, the method is doing something that you could otherwise derive that type and eliminate the Type input parameter all together.